# Power of adjacency matrix

Tags: graphs

Let $G$ be a weighted graph with a weight function $w \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^{+}$. Let $G'$ denotes the weighted matrix with adjacency matrix

$$A_{G'} = \sum_{i=0}^{k} (xA)^{i}$$

where $k$ is integer and $x$ is a variable.

I am not getting what is $A_{G'}$ matrix? Is it contains all walks of length $k$ or is it something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you probably know, $A^i_{st}$ is the total weight of walks of length $i$ from $s$ to $t$. Since
$$
\sum_{i=0}^k (xA)^i = \sum_{i=0}^k A^i x^i,
$$
the $s,t$ coefficient of $A_{G'}$ is
$$
\sum_{i=0}^k A^i_{st} x^i.
$$
This is a polynomial in which for $0 \leq i \leq k$, the coefficient of $x^i$ is the total weight of walks of length $i$ from $s$ to $t$.